# Is it possible to receive a tuple inside an actor without the warning "eliminated by erasure"

Tags: scala, tuples, akka, actor

I wonder if it is possible to receive a tuple inside an actor, without receiving this warning:

```
non-variable type argument Long in type pattern (Long, Int) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
```

although the code seems to be valid and works:

```
override def receive: Receive = {
  case tuple: (Long, DateTime) => sendPlace(tuple._1, tuple._2)
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing

```
case (id: Long, time: DateTime) => sendPlace(id, time)
```

will also avoid unchecked casts, but Łukasz is right: you should define a case class for this purpose.

> since two applications are communicating together it allows me not to define two times the case class

Of course you shouldn't define it twice. Define it once, in a library which both applications depend on. This way 1) you make it clear where applications communicate; 2) if you need to change the message type (e.g. add another field, or change the type of one of the fields), you will be much less likely to forget to change one of the sides.

> Can you just, please, explain why I don't get this warning when it is not in the context of an actor that receives a message?

You do:

```
val x: Any = ("a", "b")

x match {
  case tuple: (Long, DateTime) => 
    println("shouldn't match, but does")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tuples are generic types, e.g. `Tuple2[T1, T2]` and in the JVM those type parameters are erased and not present in the runtime. There is a lot on this topic online.

Your code works, but only thing that is checked to see if message matches the pattern is if the message is `Tuple2`, not inner its types. If this actor gets another `Tuple2`, say `(String, String)` you will get a class cast exception when trying convert `String`, to `Long` when trying to pass the first element to `sendPlace` method.

For example in following

```
override def receive: Receive = {
  case tuple: (Long, DateTime) => sendPlace(tuple._1, tuple._2)
  case tuple: (Int, Int) => sender ! (tuple._1 + tuple._2)
}
```

second pattern is unreachable, it will never match, as any `Tuple2` will match to the first pattern and throw exception if the type is wrong.

In general you should create case classes for messages. This has the benefit of a meaningful name for both the message and its members, tuple says nothing more than its types. You should define the messages that actor can handle in its companion object.

```
object BookingActor {
  case class BookingRequest(placeId: Long, bookingTime: DateTime)
}

class BookingActor {
  import BookingActor._

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case BookingRequest(id, time) => bookPlace(id, time)
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Good response thanks, please note that in the real code the names are more meaningful and I think that it is enough understandable and since two applications are communicating together it allows me not to define two times the case class, that's why I would have prefer to use a tuple. Can you just, please, explain why I don't get this warning when it is not in the context of an actor that receives a message? Does the JVM replaces the tuple by a case class?